# Create ics file and send email with Attachment using c#

Tags: c#, outlook

I need to send calendar appointment email attached with ics file contains appointment details, I am getting Mails but Attachment is missing help me, someone to overcome this

Need to create simple ics file and attach it with the email.

Please Look at below code as I tried

```
   public IHttpActionResult cal(calendar objApptEmail)
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        //Now we have to set the value to Mail message properties

        //Note Please change it to correct mail-id to use this in your application
        msg.From = new MailAddress("ssss@gmail.com", "ABC");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("ssss@outlook.com", "BCD"));
        //  msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress("zzzzz@xyz.com", "DEF"));// it is optional, only if required
        //   msg.Headers.Add("Content-class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
        msg.Subject = "Send mail with ICS file as an Attachment";
        msg.Body = "Please Attend the meeting with this schedule";

        // Now Contruct the ICS file using string builder
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting");
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+330)));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+660)));
        str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + objApptEmail.Location);
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));

        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contype = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
        contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        //  contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Meeting.ics");
        AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), contype);
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);

        //Now sending a mail with attachment ICS file.                     
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpclient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        smtpclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //-------this has to given the Mailserver IP
        smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("dddd@gmail.com", "xxxxx");
        smtpclient.Send(msg);
        return Ok();       

}
```

Comment: You are not creating an _attachment_ you are creating an _alternate view_ - that's a difference. I also suggest to extract the ics creation code into it's own class.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create a meeting request but you describe trying to **attach** an ics file. Those are two different things, which one do you want?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I removed all the code and enter the code after testing it on my machine. This is working fine in my case. In your case it's not working try to setup Less secure app in Gmail (I see you are using gmail to send emails)

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("anirudhagupta01@example.com","anirudha@testing.com");

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
            str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting");
            str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
            str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+330)));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+660)));
            str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + "abcd");
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));

            str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

            str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
            str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
            str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
            str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
            str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
            str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString());
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

            Attachment attach = new Attachment(stream,"test.ics");

            msg.Attachments.Add(attach);

            System.Net.Mime.ContentType contype = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
            contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
            //  contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Meeting.ics");
            AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), contype);
            msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);

            //Now sending a mail with attachment ICS file.                     
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpclient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            smtpclient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //-------this has to given the Mailserver IP
            smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpclient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("anirudhagupta0011@gmail.com", "testing");
            smtpclient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: Since OP has the "file" contents created as string, it may be a good addition to the answer, how he could transform that string without the need to go throught disk I/O ? (Only a suggested improvement, already +1)

Comment: @Fildor Thanks, I am updating my answer.

Comment: Thing is that ics file should create dynamically, but the above code shows file is getting static from local, Finally I need ics file should create dynamically and send mail with attachment

Comment: i gone with many samples everyone is showing the same Example

Answer (score 10):

I once had the same requirement and went well with the assembly Ical.Net.

With this library you dont need to parse all by hand but can use "normal programming" :)

```
using Ical.Net;
using Ical.Net.DataTypes;
using Ical.Net.Serialization.iCalendar.Serializers;

private static Calendar CreateCalendarEntry(DateTime? start, DateTime? end, string title, string description, string location)
{
    Calendar iCal = new Calendar();
    iCal.Method = "PUBLISH";
    // Create the event, and add it to the iCalendar
    Event evt = iCal.Create<Event>();
    // Set information about the event
    evt.Start = new CalDateTime(start.Value);
    evt.End = new CalDateTime(end.Value); // This also sets the duration  
    evt.Description = description;
    evt.Location = location;
    evt.Summary = title;
    // Create a reminder 24h before the event
    Alarm reminder = new Alarm();
    reminder.Action = AlarmAction.Display;
    reminder.Trigger = new Trigger(new TimeSpan(-24, 0, 0));
    evt.Alarms.Add(reminder);

    return iCal;
}
```

You can download the assembly [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net/)

After creating the `Calendar`, you can easily send it by mail via a stream.

Comment: @Chris What is the benefit of introducing a new dll when the code in OP is work fine.

Comment: It's easier to understand, maintain and expand. + I dont like this "doing all by raw data"-approach and try to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this lib. works pretty great for me. Hope this lib will be updated in future for any changes..

Comment: Can you extend your example @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica to show how to convert this to a binary mail attachment? - I'm not clear on how to take an Calendar object and convert that into a file attachment.

Comment: @RobMcCabe As Email is a wide area with many frameworks and providers, I'd suggest to ask this as a seperate question or google that in general like "attach ics file as binary attachment". If you just need it as MemoryStream, you can use the ical serializer like `iCalendarSerializer serializer = new iCalendarSerializer(iCal); var ms = new MemoryStream(); serializer.Serialize(iCal, ms, Encoding.UTF8);`