# How to tie location address and phone number to ICS

Tags: c#

at the moment I followed this step to send an calendar event [Create ics file and send email with Attachment using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358161/create-ics-file-and-send-email-with-attachment-using-c-sharp)

It works great, but i'm wondering if there's a way to enhance it so it also sends the location. At the moment it only sends the location name.

```
 str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + "Chateau");
```

[image]

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Whatever app that is in the screenshot, use it to create an ICS that has a phone number and address, then send the ics to yourself via email and open it in notepad; then you will know what properties to add to your own ics to make the app read a phone number and address

Comment: I've converted the comment to an answer, so it can be upvoted if you found the advice useful but I would also recommend that you post your own answer with exactly what you did and some snippet of code, so that any future visitor to this question might get some insight from it and know all the properties they should add (it will save them some time not having to repeat the investigation work you did to work out the properties). Also say what that program is in the screenshot. You can accept your own answer and future visitors will upvote it too

Comment: Hi Master, did you get any parameter in the ICS? Could you share an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be:

Whatever app that is in the screenshot, use it to create an ICS that has a phone number and address, then send the ics to yourself via email and open it in notepad; then you will know what properties to add to your own ics to make the app read a phone number and address